# Forbid select the options with "disabled" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I use *select2* and have this layout

Original code(using Twig):

```html
<select id="workerId" name="workerId" class="form-control select2 text">
            <option value="0">-- Не указано --</option>
            {% for worker_one in workerList %}
                <option data-position="{{ worker_one.position_list }}" value="{{ worker_one.id }}"
                        {% if worker_one.status != 3 %}
                            {% if sampleActs.worker_id %}
                                {% if worker_one.id == sampleActs.worker_id %}
                                    selected
                                {% endif %}
                            {% else %}
                                {% if worker_one.id == areaCore.worker_id %}
                                    selected
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% else %}
                            disabled
                        {% endif %}
                        >{{ worker_one.name }}
                </option>
            {% endfor %}    
        </select>
```

```js
$('.select2').select2();
```

```html
<select name="name">
  <option disabled>Vasia</option>
  <option>Petia</option>
  <option>Stas</option>
</select>
```

When `$("[name='name'").select2()` init in dropdown list I still can select option options with `disabled` attribute. How I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to display an unclickable select??? and your code is working, see your own snippet

Comment: Could you paste the entire code. That will make sense to understand.

Comment: *Jonas w* see original code. I need it based on project logic.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine here:

```js
$("[name='name'").select2()
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select name="name">
  <option disabled>Vasia</option>
  <option>Petia</option>
  <option>Stas</option>
</select>
```

So your issue is not related to your HTML

Comment: isnt that a comment??

Comment: Not really. The question is asking how to fix it, the answer is, according to the information given, there is no problem. Now bare in mind if the question is updated with a verifiable issue, I'll update the answer as well.

Comment: It seems that I found problem. If I use only `disabled` it is not working but when I set `disabled="disabled"` it works fine. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @MetalEvolutionStudio ah, yes. Some legacy browsers do not support boolean attribute syntax and require some sort of value to indicate a truthy status.

Answer (score -1):

Set an ID for all the option and then, on page load, maybe in the onload of the body tag, you can set this:

```
<select name="name">
  <option id="vasia">Vasia</option>
  <option id="petia">Petia</option>
  <option id="stas">Stas</option>
</select>
```

Then

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('vasia').disabled = true;">
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is bad SEO, all info regarding availability of values should be rendered directly in markup.

Comment: Maybe it could be useful for other purposes, when It could be necessary do all the things with javascript

Comment: No, that is wrong. It's always better to try and address it in markup directly, and since in this case the markup is being rendered server-side, that is the best option. JavaScript should be a last resort for rendering things related to usability, and even then should not be `eval()`'d directly in the `onload` attribute, which is an additional bad practice.